# Docker EE UCP log: unable to authenticate user with refresh token on auth provider: invalid_grant

Tags: docker-ucp, docker-ee

I see these messege in the UCP logs:

```
<3>2018-08-24T13:11:05Z ucp-controller-10.3.11.70 /bin/controller[1]: {"level":"error","msg":"unable to authenticate user with refresh token on auth provider: invalid_grant: no such account for refresh token: keyid:0bfd4f0d330d0385e56f1eb59a8d86f9a85f4fe380de53fe89f77b932f9a08b3","time":"2018-08-24T13:11:05Z"}
```

What is the cause and how to fix it.

thanks

Comment: any updates? Could you tell how you resolved ?

Comment: Hi , I had fixed it but I forgot because it was long time ago and we have switched to rancher , maybe i had deleted some stale object/value